# Android Studio 4.1 gradle resource unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

After update Android Studio to 4.1 (4.1.1 also), I'm getting unresolved reference errors for resources defined in Gradle (app level). But project builds and resources have proper values when I refer to them.

in gradle file:

```
it.resValue 'string', "test_value", "test"
```

usage:

[image]

So my problem is just getting errors, project builds and everything works as it should.
Before the updates, the problem did not occur. Ofc I've tried build/rebuild, gradle sync, invalidate cache & restart - nothing changes.
Is there anything else what I can do?

Comment: What's `it` there? Are you sure values set properly in the gradle?

Comment: It is an iterator over build types but to be more sure I moved this code to `android {} ` body and removed iterator `it`. Still works, still getting `unresolved reference`

Comment: @ploponstack have you already solved this? I got the same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not...

Comment: It's a bug about AndroidStudio, and was reported on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161727311), but unresolved.